# .Net MVC 4 -- AJAX data binding to model

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC 4, I currently have AJAX calls making POST requests to a controller. All that works fine. I don't know how to save the JSON data that is being posted into a Model that can save it. The JSON being posted can vary greatly so is there a simple way to bind it to the model and leave it flexible enough to accept JSON with varying attributes in it?

I have looked everywhere online but I cannot find an example where it is done without some other library (like Knockout.js)... Not really trying to master another library right now. Is there a 'native' way to do it without adding extra abstraction?

Go ahead and close it as 'unconstructive' if you don't like me.

Comment: Could you give us an idea on how it will vary? Different properties, number of elements, etc.?

Comment: One ajax call may be 'url' 'type' and 'color' and another may be 'url' 'type' and 'address' lets say. is this possible to update the same model?

Comment: Some people have suggested to use an array in the model to hold different types of values but this seems like a 'shortcut'. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a model that has the properties you need, and let modelbinding populate only the properties that were provided

```
public class MyObject
{
  public string Url {get; set;}
  public string Type {get; set;}
  public string Color {get; set;}
  public string Address {get; set;}
}
```

Your server-side code would then need to take into account the fact that some of the values could be empty.

Another approach is to have different objects that relate to what you are passing in:

```
public class MyObjectColor
{
  public string Url {get; set;}
  public string Type {get; set;}
  public string Color {get; set;}
}

public class MyObjectAddress
{
  public string Url {get; set;}
  public string Type {get; set;}
  public string Address {get; set;}
}
```

Then have different action methods that the client would call.

```
public ActionResult SaveMyObjectColor(MyObjectColor values)

public ActionResult SaveMyObjectAddress(MyObjectAddress values)
```

This would require that the client have some way of knowing if there is a difference in order to create the correct JSON and call the appropriate action method.

Comment: That seems like an acceptable strategy. The controller methods would be invoked by AJAX Post requests so I would assume ordering of the controller methods to not be a problem?

Comment: Ordering of controller methods is not a problem. The only time when order is taken into account is in the declaration of the `routes`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your timely and simple response thats the kick in the rear I needed!!!